# Switch tab bar view in subview programmatically (custom tab bar controller)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Because I want to redesign the tab bar UI, I wrote a custom tab bar controller according to https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

In `TabBarViewController`'s viewDidLoad(), define several subviews corresponding to each tab bar

```
homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController")
...
viewControllers = [homeViewController, searchViewController, accountViewController, trendingViewController]
```

and the main method when tapping tab

```
@IBAction func didPressTab(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let previousIndex = selectedIndex
        selectedIndex = sender.tag

        tabButtons[previousIndex!].isSelected = false
        let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex!]

        // remove previous VC
        previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

        // set current VC
        sender.isSelected = true
        let vc = viewControllers[selectedIndex]

        addChildViewController(vc)

        // Adjust the size to match content view
        vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

I could set a default tab bar index `selectedIndex` when the tab bar view is loaded. However, how can I switch to next tab bar in homeViewController (without tapping tab bar buttons)?

This doesn't work in `homeViewController`

`TabBarViewController().tabButtons[2].isSelected = true            TabBarViewController().didPressTab(TabBarViewController().tabButtons[2])`

I'm not sure how to get the running tab controller, set the selectedIndex, and update subview in the subview controllers.

Comment: How about writing this inside homeViewController:
TabBarViewController (parentViewController).selectedIndex = 2, or TabBarViewController (parentViewController).didPressTab(TabBarViewController(parentViewController).tabButtons[2])?

Comment: Do I need to modify `parentViewController`? error "unresolved identifier" appeared. btw i use swift 3.0

Comment: Sorry, just use "parent".

Comment: IDE told me to add label `coder`, `TabBarViewController(coder: parent).selectedIndex = 2`
And error
`Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController?' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'` Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like parent is an optional, so you have to unwrap it, use parent! instead of just parent.

Comment: And also, because you init a view controller from a storyboard, you should add this: required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder)! }. That's a rule.

Comment: sorry I didn't get it. I did unwrap parent. add init() in tabBatViewController. the error msg is the same (without optional"?")

Comment: Add this code inside each subclass of UIViewController that is connected to a view controller in the Storyboard: required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

Comment: I add it to five UIViewController connected to each tab. But `Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'`
Could you provide more detail about your solution? thanks!

Comment: Use `delegate` to solve this problem at answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use `Delegate` to solve.

In SubViewController add protocol

```
protocol SubViewControllerDelegate {
    func transferToView(index: Int)
}
```

and declare this in the class

`var delegate: SubViewControllerDelegate?`

In TabBarViewController set to conform `SubViewControllerDelegate`

Implement the method

```
func transferToView(index: Int) {
    tabButtons[index].isSelected = true
    didPressTab(tabButtons[index])
}
```

Set delegate

```
subViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController")
let subVC = subViewController as! SubViewController
subVC.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to call tabBar.setSelectedViewController: and pass the view controller.

If you only know the tab index, you call tabBar.viewControllers[index] and get the view controller.

Comment: is this available for ***custom*** tab bar?

Comment: if it is subclass of UITabBarController then yes

Comment: unfortunately, nope. The link above used UIViewController instead